# should I state my user information in redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

Should I safe my user information in redux state or context ?

Like email,username,isLogged

I use this in multiple components so what you recommend ?

Comment: Yes, you can store user info in redux but refrain from storing password or tokens.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using redux anyway: Yes. The user information is considered global application state and consumed by multiple components, so redux is a perfect fit.

As @rohit-aggarwal pointed out it is nowadays considered safer to not store tokens or passwords in redux. http-only cookies are a good way to restrict access to sensitive tokens from the JS runtime. They can be sent along in requests to the authentication backend without exposing them to potentially malicious JS code.